# How to mock "NOW()" for TypeORM MySQL?

Tags: mysql, node.js, testing, jestjs, typeorm

I use Jest for testing and TypeORM as ORM, MySQL is the database.

I have a time-dependent query, which will return the results if the `DAY(NOW())` is lesser than 27.

```
.andWhere('DAY(NOW()) <= 27')
```

I don't want my tests to break on 28th, how should I mock/replace it on Database?

Is there more elegant way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inject the day as a parameter. Let's say your query is called inside a function `doQuery`. Add a parameter `dayNum` to the function, used inside the function like this.

```
.andWhere(':day <= 27', { day: dayNum })
```

From production code, you call

```
var now = new Date();
doQuery(now.getDate());
```

Then in your test code, you call it with whatever `dayNum` argument is appropriate to the test case.

Comment: I also thought about it. Great solution, I wonder if there's other ways of doing that.

Comment: I'm not sure, but this kind of injection pattern is extremely widely used in order to accommodate unit testing.